# Describing situation/strategy used by someone to shift the focus in order to blame the victim

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose person A makes person B very mad because A did something very wrong. B is so mad that, he/she spilled out offensive languages. A took this opportunity to shift the focus of the topic/blaming to B using inappropriate words without addressing his/her own fault.

In English, is there a specific name for this type of argument strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of [**blame shifting**](https://www.psychopathfree.com/articles/5-types-of-narcissistic-blame-shifting.388/).

Specifically, it's called *playing the victim*.

Despite being wrong yourself, you blame shift to the person who you actually harmed and play the victim to their reaction to you.  This is a personality trait often associated with narcissistic personality disorders.  It's a form of psychological manipulation often combined or associated with [gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting).

Example:  Boyfriend cheats on girlfriend.  He gets caught by his girlfriend who becomes angry and begins to verbally abuse him in front of his friends (justifiably).  The boyfriend then tells her that he cannot believe that she'd treat him this way in front of people.